# preg_replace that only acts on the first match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I wrote 2 function. The first is like this:

```
function Find($string, $first, $last)
{
    $string = " ".$string;
    $action = strpos($string,$first);
    if ($action == 0) return "";
    $action += strlen($first);    
    $result = strpos($string,$last,$action) - $action;
    return substr($string,$action,$result);
}
```

And the second here:

```
function Replace($string)
{
    $find = Find($string, '#*','*#');
    return preg_replace('/'.$find.'/', '___', $string);
}
```

I want to replace strings that it starts with `#*` and ends with `*#`. Here is my example text : `Donec gravida #*c_01*# quam nec pulvinar #*c_02*# facilisis. Donec sed consectetur #*c_03*# lectus.`

When I use functions like this: `echo Replace($string);` Only first string replaces, others not. Like this: `Donec gravida #*___*# quam nec pulvinar #*c_02*# facilisis. Donec sed consectetur #*c_03*# lectus.`

Could you help me? How do I manage this?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Yes, I read documentation and first I tried with limiter like @Session's usage. But results are same: frustration...

Comment: Add a global flag to your regex? `/foo/g`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the limit parameter of [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/function.preg-replace).

```
preg_replace('/'.$find.'/', '___', $string, 1);
```

Comment: First I tried with limiter like @Session's usage. But results are same: frustration...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to extract the value between  a pair of marker (`#*` and `*#`), then format them into another form:

for example, convert:

```
Donec gravida #*c_01*# quam nec pulvinar #*c_02*# facilisis. 
Donec sed consectetur #*c_03*# lectus
```

to

```
Donec gravida link=?c_01 quam nec pulvinar link=?c_02 facilisis. 
Donec sed consectetur link=?c_03 lectus
```

If yes, you can use the group capture in a regular expression:

```
/(?:#\*)+([^#\*]+)+(?:\*#)/
```

the regular expression will extract the value between `#*` and `*#`.

```
<?php
$str = 'Donec gravida #*c_01*# quam nec pulvinar #*c_02*# facilisis. Donec sed consectetur #*c_03*# lectus';
$matches = array();
$ptn = '/(?:#\*)+([^#\*]+)+(?:\*#)/';
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
var_export($matches);
```

The output will be:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '#*c_01*#',
    1 => '#*c_02*#',
    2 => '#*c_03*#',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'c_01',
    1 => 'c_02',
    2 => 'c_03',
  ),
)
```

***`$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern***

So, just use `preg_replace()` to convert it.

```
<?php
$str = 'Donec gravida #*c_01*# quam nec pulvinar #*c_02*# facilisis. Donec sed consectetur #*c_03*# lectus';
$matches = array();
$ptn = '/(?:#\*)+([^#\*]+)+(?:\*#)/'; 
$str = preg_replace($ptn, 'link?=$1', $str);
echo $str, "\n"
```

The output will be:

```
Donec gravida link?=c_01 quam nec pulvinar link?=c_02 facilisis. 
Donec sed consectetur link?=c_03 lectus
```

Please notice the second argument in `preg_replace`(), it is `$matches[1]`.

Comment: This is good solution but in fact, these 2 functions will bu used generation dynamic links. I manage to get "c" and "01,02,03" values. So if the site sets to use mod_rewrite, links will be generated http://sitenme.com/c_01-title-1.html, http://sitenme.com/c_02-title-2.html and http://sitenme.com/c_03-title-3.html. But not, links will be generated http://sitenme.com/comment.php?id=1, http://sitenme.com/comment.php?id=2 and http://sitenme.com/comment.php?id=3<br /><br /> So I think I have to use 2 functions above.

Comment: @JimJerry, do you want to convert `sitenme.com/c_01-title-1.html, sitenme.com/c_02-title-2.html` to `sitenme.com/comment.php?id=1, sitenme.com/comment.php?id=2` ?

Comment: I have a CMS an I insert CMS with FCKEdior.My CMS sistem have SEO optimisation. Sıif you want to use it in setting page you can select SEO. if not, deselect it. In the other parts of site, I coded functions in class files like $forum->Seo(), $content->Seo(), $ads->Seo(). But when I add textes with FCKeditor, in that time if seo is active, links were saved with seo form. but seo is not active links were saved without seo form. I think, If I saved links like `a href="#*c_01*#">Link</a>`, when textes are shown, I can rewrite link with seo condition. Below two functions are about tihs problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a nice recyclable function - you can simply use it 'as is' by passing just a string to it OR you can pass a replace and a pattern to it as well.

```
function ReplaceChar($string, $replace = "#*___*#", $pattern = "/\#\*(.*?)\*\#/"){

    $new = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);

    return $new;

}  

$string = "Donec gravida #*___*# quam nec pulvinar #*c_02*# facilisis. Donec sed consectetur #*c_03*# lectus.";

echo ReplaceChar($string);
```

This will result in:

```
Donec gravida #*___*# quam nec pulvinar #*___*# facilisis. Donec sed consectetur #*___*# lectus.
```